# Evaluate an Array Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I can evaluate a normal Excel formula within **VBA** like:

```
Sub dural()
    MsgBox Evaluate("SUM(A1:A10)")
End Sub
```

How can I evaluate an array formula??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by **L42**, you only have to use the string variant of `Evaluate` to get it to work with array formulas.
For instance, does

```
Sub dural()
  MsgBox Evaluate("SUM(A1:A10)")
  MsgBox Evaluate("=SUM(G5:G10-F5:F10)")
  MsgBox [=SUM(G5:G10-F5:F10)]
  MsgBox [Sum(G5:G10-F5:F10)]
End Sub
```

work for you (with appropriate values in `G5:G10` and `F5:F10`)?
Some further information is [here](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsh.htm).

Comment: Based on the link, `Evaluate` always treats string formulae as *Array Formulae*. So `Evaluate("SUM(G5:G10-F5:F10)")` should be fine. I just tested it and it works.