# VBA - Evaluate returning #VALUE

Tags: vba, excel

A formula with Evaluate works fine in a test workbook.
All results are good.

**Exactlythe same code**  returns #Value in the workbook I should use (that contains other macros).
The error code is 2029.
In addition, when I only put in the sheet the formula resulting from the code (either when debugging or directly in the code), the result is correct if I do Ctrl+Shft+Enter in the cell where the formula is .

As a consequence, what I understand is that the formula is not evaluated by Application.Evaluate.
Any hints of the possible cause ?
The following is part of the code

```
Const TEMPLATE = "=INDEX({0},MATCH(1,({1}={2})*({3}={4}),{5}))"
Const MATCH_TYPE = 0

Dim originalReferenceStyle
originalReferenceStyle = xlA1
Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

Dim myFormula As String
myFormula = Replace(TEMPLATE, "{0}", amountRange.Address(External:=True))
myFormula = Replace(myFormula, "{1}", accountRange.Address(External:=True))
myFormula = Replace(myFormula, "{2}", accountCriteria.Address(External:=True))
myFormula = Replace(myFormula, "{3}", dateRange.Address(External:=True))
myFormula = Replace(myFormula, "{4}", dateCriteria.Address(External:=True))
myFormula = Replace(myFormula, "{5}", MATCH_TYPE)
myIndexMatch = Application.Evaluate(myFormula)
```

Comment: Before the evaluate line put this `msgbox myformula` and make sure it looks like you would expect.  Then copy and paste that into the cell and see if it works.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/q/27590768/11683, it should work.

Comment: Thanks but the SAME CODE works perfectly in another sheet. Evaluates works fine but not in the spreadsheet I should use, together with other macros. When I intercept the formula computed by the code, it is correct. Copied and pasted in the sheet, it gives the correct result once I press Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: If the SAME CODE works perfectly in another sheet, then have you considered inspecting your data to see if there's any error values involved in the cells you're referencing? A single `#REF!` error in the data can wreck lots of otherwise perfectly working VBA code.

Comment: Why do you change Excel's reference style by the way? Do you also change it in the other file?

Comment: Tks. The data have no errors. I saw it was necessary to change the Excel's reference style in another post but it makes no difference with one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're facing a similar problem, try reducing the length of the formula ! 
It seems that Evaluate doesn't like formulas of more than 255 characters (same with FormulaArray) !!!
Take care that if you refer to ranges with (External:=True) in your formula, the name of the file is included... In my case, reducing the file name to 2 letters did the trick !
Hope this will help...