# Is the a quicker way to determine the largest string length in an array?

Tags: excel, vba

This is a segment of code that has been troubling me, as I feel certain some simple function exists that will make looping through the array values redundant.

Instead I have used an array, a loop and a boolean to tell me whether the cells are empty (or test their length) and an If statement to run the last part of the code.

I thought perhaps Max would work but I believe that is only for integers. (See the debug.print part

```
Dim arrArchLoc As Variant
Dim boolArchLoc As Boolean
Dim rowCounter As Long

boolArchLocEmpty = False

arrArchLoc = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, colArchiveLocation), Cells(lastRow, colArchiveLocation))
For rowCounter = LBound(arrArchLoc) To UBound(arrArchLoc)
    If Cells(rowCounter, colArchiveLocation) <> "" Then boolArchLocEmpty = True
Next rowCounter

'Debug.Print workshetfunction.Max(arrArchLoc)

If boolArchLocEmpty = True Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colArchiveLocation).Value = "Arch Loc"
    Columns(colArchiveLocation).ColumnWidth = 6
End If
```

Does such a function or simple method exist?

EDIT:
Whilst that specialcells(xlCellTypeBlanks) solution looks pretty good, I would still rather get the string length solution.

My apologies, the code initially had something like...

```
If len(Cells(rowCounter, colArchiveLocation)) > 6 then...
```

but I have since removed it after having to get something in place that would work.

Is there something I could do with LEN(MAX)? I experimented with it but didn't get very far.

Comment: @urdeadboy: while the title suggest the OP looks for the longest string, in fact he is just checking if a non-empty cell exists. Probably his idea is to check if max length > 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the range is `A2:A100`, the result you want would be expressed on the sheet as an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7):

```
={MAX(LEN(A2:A100))}
```

In order to execute that from VBA as an array formula and not a regular formula, you need to [use `Evaluate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27591713/11683):

```
max_len = Evaluate("=MAX(LEN(A2:A100))")
```

Or, in terms of your code,

```
Dim arrArchLoc As Range

With ActiveSheet
  Set arrArchLoc = .Range(.Cells(2, colArchiveLocation), .Cells(lastRow, colArchiveLocation))
End With

Dim max_len As Long
max_len = Application.Evaluate("=MAX(LEN(" & arrArchLoc.Address(external:=True) & "))")
```

However it is much better to calculate it explicitly with a loop, like you were already doing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Could you explain why it's a better to use the loop rather than use Evaluate? I'm guessing because it's faster/a less resource intensive approach, but I'd be fascinated to know the reasons behind it.

Comment: You already have a `Range` that you can loop over. You are converting it back to its address so that it has to be parsed back to a `Range` inside `Evaluate` (possibly in a wrong way if you are not careful enough with the address; each sheet has its own `A2:A100`), which ultimately performs the looping anyway (because *something* has to loop over all cells, you are just hiding the loop from view). This loop is not tailored to your goals either, it builds a full list of lengths and then picks the max instead of keeping track of just one value. But really it just feels quick and dirty to me.

Comment: Quick and dirty! Phoar haha thanks for your input :D

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like so

`activesheet.range(cells(1,1),cells(10,1)).specialcells(xlCellTypeBlanks)`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to check if the range is empty or not

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print DoesRangeHaveEmptyCell(Range("A1:A10")) '<~~ Change as applicable
End Sub

Function DoesRangeHaveEmptyCell(rng As Range) As Boolean
    If rng.Cells.Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) Then _
    DoesRangeHaveEmptyCell = False Else DoesRangeHaveEmptyCell = True
End Function
```