# MATCH formula with two criteria as Worksheet Function (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, match, criteria, worksheet

Take this worksheet scenario - in the yellow cell I've used an array formula to locate the 5th row in the table:
`{=MATCH(4&"jkl",A1:A5&B1:B5,0)}`

[image: worksheet]

I can't for the life of me translate this into a VBA worksheet function. Here's what I thought would be right:

```
MsgBox WorksheetFunction.Match([4 & "jkl", .Range("A1:A5") & .Range("B1:B5")], 0)
```

Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: `MsgBox [=MATCH(4 & "jkl", A1:A5&B1:B5,0)]`?

Comment: `[]` is short for `Application.Evaluate`, though it will refuse the use of variables. When you need to handle variables, and in your case you need unless you need to handle the exact same formula, then use the latter. Offtopic: concatenating values for lookup queries is really not a great idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590768/evaluate-an-array-formula) but the proposed solution has difficulty handling the concatenated ranges, so:

Taking advantage of the fact that in VBA `MATCH()` can handle either a `Range` or an `Array`:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim arr(1 To 5, 1 To 1)

    For i = 1 To 5
        arr(i, 1) = Cells(i, 1) & Cells(i, 2)
    Next i

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        MsgBox .Match("4jlk", arr, 0)
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Also, as *GSerg* commented, we could also use `Evaluate()`:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim s As String
    s = "=MATCH(4 & ""jkl"",A1:A5 & B1:B5,0)"
    MsgBox Evaluate(s)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, James... both great solutions, phew, I was not going to get there.